# AngularJS directive above table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table, angular-template

I have table and template directive rnRow

```
<table>
<tr><td><span  class="text-primary ">0 :</span></td><td><span class="text-default "> 3</span></td></tr>
<rn-Row ng-Fieldcaption="<" ng-Fieldvalue=">"></rn-Row>
<rn-Row ng-Fieldcaption="-" ng-Fieldvalue="+"></rn-Row>
<rn-Row ng-Fieldcaption="Left" ng-Fieldvalue="Right"></rn-Row>
<tr><td><span  class="text-primary ">1 :</span></td><td><span class="text-default "> 2</span></td></tr>
</table>


 template: '<tr><td><span >{{ngFieldcaption}} :</span></td><td><span> {{ngFieldvalue}}</span></td></tr>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49uFF/

and result

- < :  >
- - : +
- Left :   Right
- 0 :  3
- 1 :  2

but I want to see

- 0 :  3
- < :  >
- - : +
- Left :   Right
- 1 :  2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use the attribute declaration

```
<body ng-app="demo">
    <table>
    <tr><td><span  class="text-primary ">0 :</span></td><td><span class="text-default "> 3</span></td></tr>
    <tr rn-Row ng-Fieldcaption="<" ng-Fieldvalue=">"></tr>
    <tr rn-Row ng-Fieldcaption="-" ng-Fieldvalue="+"></tr>
    <tr rn-Row ng-Fieldcaption="Left" ng-Fieldvalue="Right"></tr>
    <tr><td><span  class="text-primary ">1 :</span></td><td><span class="text-default "> 2</span></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: but how i can add ng-if or ng-show in template, if i want manage state of ng-if\ng-show from checkbox on page?